# Personalicé el Formulario de Registro en Laravel Breeze, pero no me Permite Registrar un Usuario

Tags: laravel

Instale el Laravel 10.1.3 con PHP 8.2.3 en un Docker Desktop.

Para manejar la autenticación de la App, instale el Breeze y modifique las vistas "register.blade.php y login.blade.php" para personalizar los formularios de registro de usuarios y de login.

Las vistas de "Registro" y "Login" además de su código, quedaron de la siguiente manera:

**register.blade.php**

```
<x-guest-layout>
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" novalidate>
    @csrf

    <!-- Document -->
    <div>
        <x-input-label class="mt-2" for="document" :value="__('Document')" />
        <x-text-input id="document" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="document" placeholder="Número de Identificación" :value="old('document')" required autofocus autocomplete="document" />
        <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('document')" class="mt-2" />
    </div>

    <!-- First Name -->
    <div>
        <x-input-label class="mt-2" for="firstName" :value="__('FirstName')" />
        <x-text-input id="firstName" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Nombres" :value="old('firstName')" required autofocus autocomplete="firstName" />
        <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('firstName')" class="mt-2" />
    </div>

    <!-- Last Name -->
    <div>
        <x-input-label class="mt-2" for="lastName" :value="__('LastName')" />
        <x-text-input id="lastName" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Apellidos" :value="old('lastName')" required autofocus autocomplete="lastName" />
        <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('lastName')" class="mt-2" />
    </div>

    <!-- Email Address -->
    <div class="mt-4">
        <x-input-label for="email" :value="__('Email')" />
        <x-text-input id="email" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" :value="old('email')" required autocomplete="username" />
        <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('email')" class="mt-2" />
    </div>

    <!-- Rol -->
    <div class="mt-4">
        <x-input-label for="rol" :value="__('Rol')" />
        <select class="border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:ring-indigo-500 rounded-md shadow-sm block mt-1 w-full" id="rol" name="rol">
            <option value="">-- Seleccione un Rol --</option>
            <option value="1">Administrador de Sistema</option>
            <option value="2">Administrador</option>
            <option value="3">Administrador de Jardín</option>
            <option value="4">Comercial</option>
            <option value="5">Logístico</option>
            <option value="6">Académico</option>
        </select>
        {{-- <x-text-input id="email" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="email" name="email" :value="old('email')" required autocomplete="username" /> --}}
        <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('rol')" class="mt-2" />
    </div>

    <!-- Password -->
    <div class="mt-4">
        <x-input-label for="password" :value="__('Password')" />

        <x-text-input id="password" class="block mt-1 w-full"
                        type="password"
                        name="password"
                        placeholder="Contraseña"
                        required autocomplete="new-password" />

        <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('password')" class="mt-2" />
    </div>

    <!-- Confirm Password -->
    <div class="mt-4">
        <x-input-label for="password_confirmation" :value="__('Confirm Password')" />

        <x-text-input id="password_confirmation" class="block mt-1 w-full"
                        type="password"
                        name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Confirme Contraseña" required autocomplete="new-password" />

        <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('password_confirmation')" class="mt-2" />
    </div>

    <div class="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
        <a class="underline text-sm text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500" href="{{ route('login') }}">
            {{ __('Already registered?') }}
        </a>

        <x-primary-button class="ml-4">
            {{ __('Register') }}
        </x-primary-button>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**login.blade.php**

```
<x-guest-layout>
<!-- Session Status -->
<x-auth-session-status class="mb-4" :status="session('status')" />

<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" novalidate>
    @csrf
    
    <!-- Document -->
    <div>
        <x-input-label class="mt-2" for="document" :value="__('Document')" />
        <x-text-input id="document" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="document" placeholder="Número de Identificación" :value="old('document')" required autofocus autocomplete="document" />
        <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('document')" class="mt-2" />
    </div>

    <!-- Password -->
    <div class="mt-4">
        <x-input-label for="password" :value="__('Password')" />

        <x-text-input id="password" class="block mt-1 w-full"
                        type="password"
                        name="password"
                        placeholder="Contraseña"
                        required autocomplete="current-password" />

        <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('password')" class="mt-2" />
    </div>

    <!-- Remember Me -->
    <div class="block mt-4">
        <label for="remember_me" class="inline-flex items-center">
            <input id="remember_me" type="checkbox" class="rounded border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500" name="remember">
            <span class="ml-2 text-sm text-gray-600">{{ __('Remember me') }}</span>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
        @if (Route::has('password.request'))
            <a class="underline text-sm text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                {{ __('Forgot your password?') }}
            </a>
        @endif

        <x-primary-button class="ml-3">
            {{ __('Log in') }}
        </x-primary-button>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de esto, cree dos migraciones que agregaban los campos nuevos de los formularios de Registro y Login en la tabla "create_users_table.php".

Las migraciones creadas son las siguientes:

**add_rol_to_users_table.php**

```
    <?php

    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

    return new class extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         */
        public function up(): void
        {
            Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->integer('rol');
                //1 = Administrador de Sistema
                //2 = Administrador
                //3 = Administrador de Jardín
                //4 = Comercial
                //5 = Logístico
                //6 = Académico
            });
        }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('rol');
        });
    }
};
```

**add_document_first_name_last_name_to_users_table.php**

```
    <?php

    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

    return new class extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         */
        public function up(): void
        {
            Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->string('document')->unique();
                $table->string('firstName');
                $table->string('lastName');
            });
        }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('document');
            $table->dropColumn('firstName');
            $table->dropColumn('lastName');
        });
    }
};
```

Después, agregue estos campos nuevos en el "App/Models/user.php" el cual quedo de la siguiente manera:

**user.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'document',
        'firstName',
        'lastName',
        'email',
        'rol',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Luego modifique el "App/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisteredUserController.php" para crear en el controlador estos campos y añadirles validaciones.

El controlador quedo de la siguiente manera:

**registeredUserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\View\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;

class RegisteredUserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the registration view.
     */
    public function create(): View
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
public function store(Request $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'document' => ['required', 'string', 'max:10'],
        'firstName' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'lastName' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:'.User::class],
        'rol' => ['required', 'numeric', 'between:1,6'],
        'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
    ]);

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'document' => $request->document,
        'firstName' => Str::upper($request->firstName),
        'lastName' => Str::upper($request->lastName),
        'email' => $request->email,
        'rol' => $request->rol,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
    ]);

    event(new Registered($user));

    Auth::login($user);

    return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
}
}
```

Y finalmente corrí las migraciones usando el comando "sail artisan migrate" como indica la documentación de Laravel.

En teoría, si lleno el formulario de "Registro" y doy clic en el botón "REGISTER", el nuevo usuario quedaría registrado y sus datos pasarían a la base de datos, pero eso no está ocurriendo.

Yo uso DBeaver para verificar si llega la información a la Base de datos, pero no se registra nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además, cuando se hace clic en el botón "REGISTER" se queda en la misma ventana del formulario de registro y no pasa a la ventana del Dashboard, como debería hacerlo normalmente.

He mirado la documentación de Laravel y seguido todos los pasos que indican allí, pero no ha funcionado, además también he investigado en internet sobre el tema, pero hace falta documentación sobre este problema. Creo que puede ser algo que tal vez yo pase por alto, por eso he enviado el código de todo lo que he modificado en el proyecto para ver si ustedes ven algo dentro del código que yo no pude ver y me falto modificar.

En resumen, necesito ayuda en tres cosas puntuales:

1. Lograr que pueda registrar usuarios nuevos.
2. Deshabilitar la confirmación de creación de cuenta de usuario que
   pide el Breeze por medio del correo electrónico.
3. Poder realizar Login de usuario con el número de documento y la
   contraseña.

Agradezco mucho su ayuda con este inconveniente.